# SharePoint 2010 "The security validation for this page is invalid" during "Check Out" with Javascript REST

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In a specific client's environment, using Check Out causes the error "The Security validation for this page is invalid". I have exhausted all I can think of as far as code, but I am not able to replicate in another environment. Other clients do not have this issue with the same exact code.

In Fiddler, the exception occurs during the Client.svc/ProcessQuery call.

The specific javascript code to execute the operation is as follows:

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext(srvRelUrl);
var spWeb = context.get_site().openWebById(new SP.Guid(webId));
var spFile = spWeb.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(GetRelative(fileUri));
UpdateFormDigest((window)._spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl, (window)._spFormDigestRefreshInterval);
spFile.checkOut();
```

Where in there SP environment can I investigate the issue? I have not checked anything regarding DNS or the SP Security because I don't really know where to look.

The FQDN is in the client's Trusted Sites.
The user does have appropriate permissions to check out.
The FormDigest is generated properly and validates.